# How to inform the server when a client is interrupted?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

How to inform the server if a client is interrupted, and then close the socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the other end of a socket is closed, your end will be marked as readable and return `0` from `read` - this is the "end of file" indication.

If you try to `write` to such a socket, you will recieve the `SIGPIPE` signal, and the `write` will return error with errno set to `EPIPE` ("Broken Pipe").  You must be prepared to handle this event, because the other end can close the socket at *any* time.

Comment: Thanks! could you plz give more details on how to do it? also  when e.g, ctrl-c is pressed on the side of client, should we return also a SIGINt signal? thanks again for your help

Comment: @Apollo Signals aren't sent between different computers

Comment: If ctrl-c is used to terminate the client application, the OS will close the connection and the server process will be able to detect that as an end-of-file condition.

Comment: Isn't this too X-nix specific?

Comment: Thanks! actually I am working on different OSs (Unix and win_32). How to inform the server which is running windows that client is interrupted? Can you plz help me? thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You need TCP_KEEPALIVE

Comment: thanks! but if ctrl-c is pressed , how should we deal with it?

Comment: Keepalive (SO_KEEPALIVE is name of socket option, btw) has nothing to do with it. OP didn't ask about detecting half-opened connections